# How to compare two dataframes and delete the non matched rows from dataframes in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a newbie to python (especially pandas).

I have two dataframes df1 & df2. df1 has 200 rows. df2 has 250 rows. The index values also contains duplicates.

```
df1:
ProcessID
      248
      436
      500
      500
```

Another data frame

```
ProcessID   Day      Time     Status
      248   Sun  23:26:51  completed
      436   Sat  01:50:56  completed
      500   Thu  14:18:21  completed
      500   Wed  23:00:15  Completed
```

I wanted to know how to compare both dataframes in pandas based on the processID (which is the index in both df's). Based on the comparison I wanted to remove the excess rows in df2.

It will be of great help if someone can guide me.

Comment: By saying "remove the excess rows in df2", do you want the ProcessIDs which exist in both `df1` and `df2` to be included or excluded? I am not clear because you wrote "delete the non matched rows" in the title.

Comment: Please provide an excerpt of `df2` and desired output. Also read *[mcve]*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build sets from the index. and remove the duplicates that are in both indexes

```
duplicates = set(df1.index).intersection(df2.index)
df2 = df2.drop(duplicates, axis=0)
```